# Get PushNotification when sending a mail in EWS Subscription

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get a notification when i send a message but it's only happening when I receive a new one, even if i'm subscribed to all Folders.

here is a sample of my code:

````
//Getting all folders of the user
List<Folder> listFolder = new List<Folder>();
listFolder = FindAllFoldersToPickUp();
FolderId[] listID = new FolderId[listFolder.Count];
for (int i = 0; i != listFolder.Count; i++)
    listID[i] = listFolder.ElementAt(i).Id;

registerMessage = callback;

// subscribe to events
subscription = accountExchangeService.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(listID, EventType.NewMail);

//Start subscription
connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(accountExchangeService, 30);
connection.AddSubscription(subscription);
connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnEvent;
connection.OnDisconnect += OnSubscribeDisconnect;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You only get NewMail notifications on the Inbox when mail is delivered if you subscribe to CreatedEvent on Folders you should see an event when the copy of the Sent Email is saved in the SentItems folder. (but there is a distinction between Saved and NewEmail delivered to the Inbox)